# How do I use the field tag in a user defined tag with the Play! Framework?

Tags: playframework

Right now I have a view like this that works.

```
#{form @UserCreate.create()}
    #{field 'user.email'}
        #{text field /}
    #{/field}
#{/form}
```

With a corresponding text tag defined which then uses the field (it is more complicated than this, just boiling down to essentials)

```
<input type="text" id="${_arg.id}" name="${_arg.name}" value="${_arg.value}">
```

Ideally I would rather have it so I did not have to declare the field in the view so it would look like this.

```
#{form @UserCreate.create()}
    #{text 'user.email' /}
#{/form}
```

With a tag that looks like this.

```
#{field 'user.email'}
    <input type="text" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}">
#{/field}
```

But the field.value always returns null because user is not in the tags' template binding.  I am not really sure how to approach things at this point.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to do what you want due to the way the #{field} tag works (see its code [here](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/FastTags.java#L136)).

Probably the best approach is to create a series of fast tags based on Field tag's code, without the part that renders the body (as you won't need it), even if it may mean a bit of code duplication. Once done you can refactor to extract some common sections and reduce the duplication.

Comment: Nice code reference, I saw that yesterday and was thinking of hijacking it like you suggested, but I thought I might have just been missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have an interesting workaround:
Just write the first line of the custom tag

```
 %{user = _user}%  
 #{field 'user.email'}  
    <input type="text" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}">    
 #{/field}
```

This works for me :)

Comment: I think you miss the point.  He doesn't(nor do I) want "user.email" in there, especially the email as we want to re-use it for user.email, user.name, user.firstName, user.parentsName, etc. etc.  and hopefully user is abstracted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the field tag quite a bit myself.  I still have to do this to use it :( :(

```
#{xfield objectId:'groupDbo.name',label:'Group Name', help:'Some help message', length:'50'}
    #{text field/}
#{/xfield}
```

but I don't have to keep repeating this html at least......

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <span class="label ${_arg.errorClass}">${_arg.label}</span>
    <span class="input ${_arg.errorClass}">
        <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="${_arg.name}" value="${_arg.value}" maxlength="${_arg.length}">
        <a id="newinfo" class="help" title="${_arg.help}">${_arg.help}</a>
        <span class="error">${_arg.error}</span> 
    </span>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

This also fixes a bug(in 1.2.x) they have in the field tag in which that don't get private fields which is very annoying....(and adds more fields that should be there and are not)

```
public class TagHelp extends FastTags {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TagHelp.class);

    public static void _xfield(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out, ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
        Map<String,Object> field = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Object objId = args.get("objectId");
        if(objId == null || !(objId instanceof String))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'objectId' param must be supplied to tag xfield as a String");
        Object label = args.get("label");
        if(label == null || !(label instanceof String))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'label' param must be supplied to tag xfield as a String");
        Object length = args.get("length");
        if(length == null || !(length instanceof String))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'length' param must be supplied to tag xfield as a String");
        Object help = args.get("help");
        if("".equals(help))
            help = null;
        String _arg = objId.toString();
        Object id = _arg.replace('.','_');
        Object flashObj = Flash.current().get(_arg);
        Object flashArray = new String[0]; 
        if(flashObj != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(flashObj.toString()))
            flashArray = field.get("flash").toString().split(",");
        Object error = Validation.error(_arg);
        Object errorClass = error != null ? "hasError" : "";
        field.put("name", _arg);
        field.put("label", label);
        field.put("length", length);
        field.put("help", help);
        field.put("id", id);
        field.put("flash", flashObj);
        field.put("flashArray", flashArray);
        field.put("error", error);
        field.put("errorClass", errorClass);
        String[] pieces = _arg.split("\\.");
        Object obj = body.getProperty(pieces[0]);
        if(obj != null){
            if(pieces.length > 1){
                for(int i = 1; i < pieces.length; i++){
                    try{
                        Field f = getDeclaredField(obj.getClass(), obj, pieces[i]);
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        if(i == (pieces.length-1)){
                            try{
                                Method getter = obj.getClass().getMethod("get"+JavaExtensions.capFirst(f.getName()));
                                field.put("value", getter.invoke(obj, new Object[0]));
                            }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                                field.put("value",f.get(obj).toString());
                            }
                        }else{
                            obj = f.get(obj);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        log.warn("Exception processing tag on object type="+obj.getClass().getName(), e);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                field.put("value", obj);
            }
        }
        body.setProperty("field", field);
        body.call();
    }

    private static Field getDeclaredField(Class clazz, Object obj, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        if(clazz == Object.class)
            throw new NoSuchFieldException("There is no such field="+fieldName+" on the object="+obj+" (obj is of class="+obj.getClass()+")");
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
            return getDeclaredField(clazz.getSuperclass(), obj, fieldName);
        }
    }

}
```